# Infragistics Webdatagrid: Resize column to largest header/data cell contents

Tags: infragistics, webdatagrid

I am searching for a solution that changes the column width based on largest data content or header.
Solutions like
        tbody.igg_Item > tr > td
        {
            white-space: nowrap !important;
        }
does not work because the grid sets the column width based on the column header contents not the data, thus the data cell contents is not displayed in its full length.
e.g if content is "my test data content", I can only see "my test dat" because my header is not long enough.

My markup is:

```
     <ig:WebDataGrid ID="WebDataGrid1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="350px"
         Width="100%">
         <ClientEvents MouseDown="GridMouseDown" />
         <Behaviors>
             <ig:Activation>
             </ig:Activation>
             <ig:ColumnResizing>
             </ig:ColumnResizing>
             <ig:Selection CellSelectType="Single">
             </ig:Selection>
         </Behaviors>
    </ig:WebDataGrid>
```

I am adding the columns in code behind (I have not seen any DataColumn property that controls width)

Answer (score 1):

The grid will automatically size the columns to the data portion of the grid if there is no width set on the column and the grid itself doesn't have a width.  Note that you will need to put the grid in a container if you want a horizontal scroll bar and if using paging the pager will scroll with the columns.

I have a more detailed answer to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13711080/efficient-way-to-measure-longest-cell-in-table-column/14988075#14988075) on StackOverflow.  I also have this posted in the Infragistics forums [here](http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/p/24800/404617.aspx#404617) with a sample.  I also have a modification of that example that allows wrapping of text in the header if there are multiple words with sample posted [here](http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/p/24800/405121.aspx#405121).

Comment: The solutions, described on links, use an outside div for resizing and scrollbars but grid will not be able to use fixed headers - which is one of the main reasons of using IG grid instead of html table, furthermore if we have 500 rows you will have 2 scrollbars(one for outside div + one from grid) using the demos on the link. How can we address issues mentioned above? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by fixed headers?  The outside container doesn't need to have a height set and you can still use the height of the grid so that the headers don't scroll.  The samples that I provided on the Infragistics forums don't have two scroll bars.  Do you have an example that does?

Comment: IG doco called header or column header(http://www.infragistics.com/products/aspnet/sample/data-grid/dynamic-columns). In the this link you will notice that the first row (header) does not not move when you use the vertical scrollbar. We cannot do that if the vertical scrollbar is in the outside grid as the whole content moves. Notice that in our case we are dealing number of rows ranging from 1 to 1000, thus the need for the vertical scrollbar.

Comment: To get around that you would need to change the DOM so that the grids scroll bar isn't present, add a container with content outside of the grid that can provide a scroll bar and manually update the grids scroll position when your external scroll bar is moved.  I would encourage you to submit a feature request if you haven't done so already: https://www.infragistics.com/my-account/feature-request/